# C/C++ How to read from stdin after enter is hit twice in a row or after 2 newlines

Tags: c++, c, input, stdin

I'm trying to have the user input a block of text to the console that my program will read from stdin only after enter has been hit twice in a row or, said in a different way, when enter is hit on an already blank line.  But, I want to continue reading from stdin so basically, only read from stdin when enter is hit while on an already blank line.  Then flush and restart.

Example of user input:

```
Hello(\n)
World(\n)
(\n)
(Read Now)
```

I haven't been able to find an input function capable of specifying this behavior.

Also, I've tried a few methods using single character retrieval functions but I haven't been able to get it work correctly.

Anyone know of a way to do this elegantly?

Answer implemented:

```
char word[100];
int i = 0;
while ((word[i++] = getchar())!='\n' || (word[i++]=getchar())!='\n');
printf("%s",word);
```

Obviously buffer overflow needs to be dealt with before using this. Just an example.

Comment: Read line by line and set a flag when you read an empty line.

Comment: What does "flush and restart" even mean? You specified the semantics of your program are really poorly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you want to ignore the input until the sequence `\n\n`. You can do it with:

```
while (getchar()!='\n' || getchar()!='\n');
//read the input now
```

Comment: BEAUTIFUL, short and simple. I figured there was a better method than the lengthy solutions I'd come up with.

Answer (score 2):

Ignore everything until you read in a blank line, then stop ignoring.

```
// Untested code
std::string s;
// Ignore first block
while(std::getline(std::cin, s) && !s.empty()) {
  /* nothing */
  ;
}
// Don't ignore the second block
while(std::getline(std::cin, s)) {
  std::cout << "You typed: " << s << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a filtering stream buffer which reads lines as they come in but blocks forwarding characters until it has seen two newlines. It could then pretend this is all what is to be expected until something resets it. The code would look something like this:

```
class blockbuf: public std::streambuf {
public:
    blockbuf(std::streambuf* sbuf): sbuf_(sbuf), blocked_(false) {}
    int underflow() {
        std::istream in(this->blocked_? 0: this->sbuf);
        for (std::string line; std::getline(in, line) && !line.empty(); ) {
             this->buffer_ += line + "\n";
        }
        if (this->in_) {
            this->buffer_ += "\n";
        }
        this->setg(this->buffer_.c_str(), this->buffer_.c_str(),
                   this->buffer_.c_str() + this->buffer_.size());
        this->blocked_ = true;
        return this->gptr() == this->egptr()
             ? traits_type::eof()
             : traits_type::to_int_type(*this->gptr());
    }
    void unblock() { this->blocked_ = false; }

private:
    std::streambuf* sbuf_;
    bool            blocked_;
    std::string     buffer_;
};
```

You would use this stream buffer something like this (if you want to use it via `std::cin` you can use `std::cin.rdbuf()` to replace `std::cin`'s stream buffer):

```
blockbuf b(std::cin.rdbuf());
std::istream in(&b);
for (std::string block; std::getline(in, block, 0); b.unblock(), in.clear()) {
     processAllLinesUpToEmptyLine(block);
}
```

Obviously, there are many variations on how to play this game...